# For Entityframework 3. When work with Database First approach, how to avoid bridge tables

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Business case is: A message is sent with a list of contracts, and message should be stored in database.  A contract can belong to several messages, a report can show messages related to certain contract but this is not related to my code. My code need only to store messages, one message at a time.

I have 3 tables Message, Contract, and ContractMessage.  I use schema first (database first) approach, ContractMessage entity is created.  I don't need that entity, I only need a property of type List< Contract> inside message.  and currently I am not even interested to have a List< Message> inside the contract.

I am new to EF and I hear that EF 1 is full of troubles. should I keep the bridge tables? Can remove bridge tables and convert it to properties and How to remove those bridge tables from the model and how mapping should be fixed.

Comment: "and currently I am not even interested to have a List< Message> inside the contract." -- Do you mean you do not care whether you have that property, or do you mean you really want to not have that property?

Comment: @hvd I don't think navigability is the main issue here. More that you can't model a many-to-many relationship without a join table, but that you don't necessarily want said table to be an entity in your C# code.

Comment: @hvd, Yes I don't care whether I have this property or not

Comment: @Costa By "schema first", do you mean what the MSDN docs call ["Database First"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx) or ["Model First"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424)?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your database schema as well as screenshot of what your .edmx model looks like? I didn't think EF would show the bridge tables if you had primary keys and relationships setup.

Comment: @millimoose I mean database first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Entity Framework creates the bridge table as an entity with database-first approach it usually means that the bridge table does not have the required schema to be recognized as the bridge table of a many-to-many relationship - which is:

- The bridge table must have **exactly** `(number of primary key columns in left entity) + (number of primary key columns in right entity)` columns. For example: If your left and right entity tables (`Contract` and `Message`) don't have composite keys, just a single primary key column, the number of columns in the bridge table must be **exactly** `2`.
- **All** columns in the bridge table must form a single composite primary key.
- Between the primary key(s) of the left entity table and first column(s) in the bridge table a **foreign key constraint** must be defined in the database, i.e. the first column(s) in the bridge table are foreign key(s) to the left entity table.
- The same applies to the right entity table and the last column(s) in the bridge table.
- I am not sure about this point (especially not for EF 1) but it might be required that the two foreign key relationships mentioned above must have **cascading delete** enabled.

If these rules are fulfilled the bridge table shouldn't be created as an entity. This applies to all versions of Entity Framework including EF 1.

If one of these requirements is not met EF won't detect the many-to-many relationship and create the bridge table as an entity.

It might depend on the details which requirement isn't fulfilled but generally I'd say you can't change the EF model to define a working many-to-many relationship without changing the database schema accordingly. For example, if you had a separate primary key column in the bridge table (in addition to the FKs to the left and right entity) you will probably have to keep the bridge entity in your model.

Best solution is to adjust the database schema so that it fulfills the above rules - if you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

If your bridge table doesn't have any interesting column (other than just `MessageId` and `ContractId`), then it's just useless in your model.

And you only want to `Message.Contracts` navigation property (you don't need `Contract.Messages`).

With Model First approach, just drag & drop you 2 entities to the designer and configure a **many-to-many association**:

[image]

As you don't need `Contract.Messages`, just click on the navigation property and delete it.

When you create the database schema from the model, Entity Framework will generate the bridge table for you :

```
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all tables
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating table 'Messages'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Messages] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'Contracts'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contracts] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'MessageContract'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MessageContract] (
    [Messages_Id] int  NOT NULL,
    [Contracts_Id] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all PRIMARY KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating primary key on [Id] in table 'Messages'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Messages]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Messages]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [Id] in table 'Contracts'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contracts]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Contracts]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [Messages_Id], [Contracts_Id] in table 'MessageContract'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MessageContract]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_MessageContract]
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Messages_Id], [Contracts_Id] ASC);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating foreign key on [Messages_Id] in table 'MessageContract'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MessageContract]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MessageContract_Message]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Messages_Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Messages]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Contracts_Id] in table 'MessageContract'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MessageContract]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MessageContract_Contract]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Contracts_Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Contracts]
        ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_MessageContract_Contract'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_MessageContract_Contract]
ON [dbo].[MessageContract]
    ([Contracts_Id]);
GO
```

Comment: The OP said they're using the schema first approach. Maybe they mean "database first", in which case I'm not sure if this answers the question

Comment: Yes my question is how to remove those bridge tables from the model and I don't know how mapping should be fixed.

Comment: @millimoose I understood "schema" as "model". Maybe I'm wrong, hopefully the OP will clarify its question.

Comment: @ken2k Going by their phrasing I thought that it says that the database tables are what a model is created from, but factoring in the possibility of ESL I admit that's not really conclusive.